# On insertion record Scheduler class not working

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have `Partner_Lead__c` object.

I have a scheduled Apex class that creates Accounts from the `Partner_Lead__c` object

The `Partner_Lead__c.email_address__c` field should be copied into `Account.Subscription_Email__c` field

Problem is `Account.Subscription_email__c` field is Unique field. When I create 2 Lead records with same mail id then got an error-

```
EXCEPTION: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: Subscription_Email__c duplicates value on record with id: 001N000000ZejC0: []
STACKTRACE: AnonymousBlock: line 101, column 1
```

**Scheduler Class-**

```
global class PartnerLeadtoAccountScheduler implements Schedulable  {

   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
   {  
    Boolean inserFlag = false;
    Boolean updateFlag = false;
    map<Id, Account> mapAccount = new map<Id, Account>();
    set<string> checkDuplicateEmail = new set<string>();

     List <Partner_Lead__c> partnerLead = [Select id,Business_Nature__c,Company_Name__c,Contact_Number__c,Contact_Person__c,Date__c
                                          ,Designation__c,Email_Address__c,Package_Plan__c,OwnerId,CP_Name_Text__c,Updated__c FROM Partner_Lead__c WHERE Email_Address__c != Null order by CreatedDate desc];   

     Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt = rtName.get('Lead').getRecordTypeId();     

     Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName1 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt1 = rtName.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();

     mapAccount = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT id,Subscription_Email__c,Channel_Partner__c,Closure_Source__c,RecordTypeId FROM Account]);
     for(account acc: mapAccount.values()){
         checkDuplicateEmail.add(acc.Subscription_Email__c);
     }                                   

     system.debug('mapAccount'+mapAccount);
     List<Partner_Lead__c> partnerleadToBeUpdated=new List<Partner_Lead__c>();
     List<Account> account = new List<Account>();
     Partner_Lead__c plead;

     for(Partner_Lead__c pl :partnerLead)
     {
        plead=new Partner_Lead__c(id=pl.id);
        if(!checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c))
        {
             Account acc = new Account();
               acc.LastName = pl.Contact_Person__c;
               acc.RecordTypeId = rt;
               acc.Business_Type__c = pl.Business_Nature__c;
               acc.Company_Name__c =pl.Company_Name__c;
               acc.Phone = pl.Contact_Number__c;
               acc.Designation__c = pl.Designation__c;
               acc.Subscription_Email__c = pl.Email_Address__c;
               acc.AccountSource = 'Channel Partner';
               acc.Channel_Partner__c = True;
               acc.Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
               acc.CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
               acc.Cp_Date__c = pl.Date__c;
               acc.CP_Name_Text__c = pl.CP_Name_Text__c;
               plead.Updated__c=true;
               //p1.Updated__c=true;
        partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead);       
        account.add(acc); 
        //inserFlag = true;
        //updateFlag = false;
        system.debug('acc'+acc);
        }
        //plead=new Partner_Lead__c(id=pl.id);
        if(checkDuplicateEmail.contains(pl.Email_Address__c)){

        Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName2 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt2 = rtName.get('Lead').getRecordTypeId();     

         Map < string, schema.RecordTypeInfo > rtName3 = schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
        Id rt3 = rtName.get('Merchant').getRecordTypeId();


            Account ac = [Select Id,Subscription_Email__c,RecordTypeId  from Account where Subscription_Email__c =:pl.Email_Address__c Limit 1];
            system.debug('--ac--'+ac);
            system.debug('--rt3--'+rt3);
            system.debug('--rt2--'+rt2);

            if(mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c == 'Organic' && mapAccount.get(ac.Id).RecordTypeId == rt3){
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Channel_Partner__c = true;
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c = 'Channel Partner';
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name_Text__c = pl.CP_Name_Text__c; 
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Cp_Date__c = pl.Date__c; 
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
            plead.Updated__c=true;
            system.debug('--plead.Updated__c--'+plead.Updated__c);
            //mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Updated__c = true;
            inserFlag = false;
            updateFlag = true;
            partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead); 
            }
            else if(mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Closure_Source__c != 'Organic'&& mapAccount.get(ac.Id).RecordTypeId == rt2){
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Channel_Partner__c = true;
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name__c = pl.OwnerId;
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).CP_Name_Text__c = pl.CP_Name_Text__c;
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Package_Plan__c = pl.Package_Plan__c;
            mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Cp_Date__c = pl.Date__c; 
            plead.Updated__c=true;
            system.debug('--plead.Updated__c--'+plead.Updated__c);
            //mapAccount.get(ac.Id).Updated__c = true;
            inserFlag = false;
            updateFlag = true;  
            partnerleadToBeUpdated.add(plead); 
            }
        }
     }
     system.debug('--inserFlag--'+inserFlag);
     system.debug('--updateFlag-'+updateFlag);
     //if(inserFlag == false){
        system.debug('Account'+account);
        insert account;
    // }
     system.debug('--inserFlagfinal--'+inserFlag);
     //if(updateFlag == true){
        update mapAccount.values();
         //if( !partnerleadToBeUpdated.isEmpty())
        update partnerleadToBeUpdated;
     //}

   }

}
```

Comment: if your field is unique then obvious you will get this issue. `first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: Subscription_Email__c`.

If you are sure `Subscription_Email__c` field can be duplicate values then just disable the unique property from `Subscription_Email__c` field.

Comment: So what is the business intent -- if an Account already exists with the `Partner_Lead__c.email_address__c` then don;t create an Account in the scheduled Apex?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Got My Solution

Here I used Map instead of list in insert condition

```
Map<string,Account> mapSAB = new Map<string, Account>();

    for(Account acc1:accountList)
                  {   
                    system.debug('--acc1--'+acc1);          
                     mapSAB.put(acc1.Subscription_Email__c, acc1);
                     system.debug('--mapSAB--'+mapSAB);
                  }

            if(!mapSAB.values().isEmpty())
           {

                insert mapSAB.values();
                system.debug('--mapSAB.values()--'+mapSAB.values());
            }
```